# Arrgregate $out mongodb insert for $out failed duplicate Error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Query1: i was trying to combine two collection with selected field of both collections using mongodb Aggregate $lookup as follows

```
 db.col1.aggregate([
   {
       $lookup: {
          from: "col2",
          localField: "field1",    
          foreignField: "field2", 
          as: "user"
       }
   },
   {
       $unwind:"$user"
   },
   { $project: { "userfield": "$user.field",col1field:1 } },
  {$out:"new_col"}
 ])


**Error:**

*"errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 4275, err: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.tmp.agg_out.1 index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5b16305d145a5117552836ec') }', code: 11000, n: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
**"code" : 16996***

----------
```

Query2: In projection i have added _id:0

```
 db.col1.aggregate([
   {
       $lookup: {
          from: "col2",
          localField: "field1",    
          foreignField: "field2", 
          as: "user"
       }
   },
   {
       $unwind:"$user"
   },
   { $project: { "userfield": "$user.field",col1field:1 ,**_id:0**} },
  {$out:"new_col"}
 ])

**Error:**
no error and no output
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `$lookup` stage simply returns multiple entries in the `user` field which then get flattened into individual subdocuments that have the same `_id` value. You can validate this by replacing the `$out` stage with a `$match` instead:

```
db.col1.aggregate([{
    $match: { _id: ObjectId('5b16305d145a5117552836ec') }
}
```

The key here is to understand how `$unwind` works. Imagine you have the following document:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    users: [ 'a', 'b' ]
}
```

Once you `$unwind` this you will get the following two documents:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    users: 'a'
},
{
    _id: 1,
    users: 'b'
}
```

So you get the same `_id` value for two different documents!

Now, when you specify `_id: 0` in your projection you remove the `_id` field from all documents which will cause MongoDB to automatically create new `_id`s which of course then works.

Comment: thanks, but i know all this things, so do you have any other solution to do this job.

Comment: If you tell me what exactly you are trying to achieve then I shall happily come up with a solution to your problem.

Comment: i want to store query output

Answer (score 0):

Ok for duplicated id explanation. In addition, if you want to keep user._id, add `id:"$_id"` to your last project stage.

But for the second query with _id:0, what do you mean by 'no error and *no output* :

- If your query is running well, results will be inserted in a new collection called 'new_col', so you have to run db.getCollection("new_col").find({}); to retrieve them. Nothing in console with $out stage!
- If your new_col collection doesn't exist or is empty : your query is returning nothing, no matter of $out stage. In this case, please provide col1 and col2 document samples

---EDIT---
With these data :

```
col1 : 
{ 
"_id" : 1.0, 
"field1" : "a", 
"field2" : "b"
}
col2 : 
{ 
"_id" : 1.0, 
"field1" : "a", 
"field2" : "c"
}
```

the right query to achieve what you need is the following :

```
db.col1.aggregate(
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $lookup: {
             from: "col2",
                  localField: "field1",    
                  foreignField: "field1", 
                  as: "user"
        }
    },
    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$user",

        }
    },
    // Stage 3
    {
        $project: {
           "userfield": "$user.field1",field1:1
        }
    },

]
);
```

Will output :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "field1" : "a", 
    "userfield" : "a"
}
```

Comment: i dont want to keep _id field of my last project,

Comment: @mathPen 
1.i know that there will be no console output of $out, but when i run "show collections" command the new collection does not showed in the list of collections.
2.if i don't pipe $out in aggregation query, then given an output, 
Collections Schema:
col1:
{_id:1,
field1:'a'
field2:'b'}

col2:
{_id:2,
field1:'a'
field2:'c'}

Comment: with those data, your query will not return anything! you're doing lookup between col1.field1 and col2.field2, but those values are different. So after lookup 'user' field is an empty array, and after unwind you get no more result. Edit my answer with complete right query.